# How to create an instance of an abstract class that passes an interface into its constructor?

Tags: java, generics, instance, abstract

Right now, I have a generic class `USetSet<T>` that extends `AbstractSet<T>` that I want to invoke. It may me important to note that `USetSet<T>`'s constructor takes in an interface `USet<T>`. The class `USetSet<T>` is as follows:

```
package bag_assignment1;

import java.util.AbstractSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

public class USetSet<T> extends AbstractSet<T> {
    USet<T> s;

    public USetSet(USet<T> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean contains(Object x) {
        return s.find((T)x) != null;
    }

    public boolean add(T x) {
        return s.add(x);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public boolean remove(Object x) {
        return s.remove((T)x) != null;
    }

    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return s.iterator();
    }

    public int size() {
        return s.size();
    }

    public void clear() {
        s.clear();
    }
}
```

For reference, the `USet<T>` interface is:

```
package bag_assignment1;

public interface USet<T> extends Iterable<T> {
    public int size();
    public boolean add(T x);
    public T remove(T x);
    public T find(T x);
    public void clear();
}
```

And right now, in another class I am trying to create an insance of `USetSet<T>`. Normally, this syntax would work with generics in my project using Integers to pass into.

```
USetSet<Integer> coolBag=new USetSet<Integer>(Integer.class);
```

However, I don't know if I need to pass in a `USet<T>` into `USetSet<T>` in this case to make it work. Is there a way I can create an instance of `USetSet<T>`?

Comment: your class *needs* an instance of `USet` of type `Integer`. So you need an implementation which you then can pass to your `USetSet`. My guess would be to subclass an already existing set and then implement your interface

Answer (score 0):

Trivially, you can create it using `new USetSet<>(null)`. Of course, it fails whenever you call one of the instance methods...

So instead, just create a class which implements the `USet` interface, and pass that in, e.g.

```
new USetSet<>(new USet<Integer>() {
  // Implement methods.
})
```

Or:

```
class USetImpl implements USet<Integer> {
  // Implement methods.
}

new USetSet<>(new USetImpl())
```